# How to get real IP from user in container (NOT HTTP) using docker bridge networking mode?

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, minecraft

## Nginx & Minecraft Server

I have many services built with docker in my server,
e.g. `Web (Nginx)`, `Database (MySQL)`, `Discord Bot`...

Before this, I only had the need for the web applications to get the user's real IP.
So I set the Nginx reverse proxy, and it working as well.
Only I need to do is sending the header `X-REMOTE-ADDR` to the app container.

But, One of thoese services is `Minecraft Server`.
It's not using HTTP protocol... So maybe I can't no longer use Nginx as my reverse proxy like before.
But I do have the need to get the user IP in the application...

## Why don't use `host` networking mode

Like I said, my server has many services running,
If I set networking mode to "host" to them, and one of thoese apps got the vulnerability... like RCE, then hacker may can access any other containers by IP 172.xx.xx.xx, um... it's too dangerous.

Please help me, on the premise that "`containers cannot communicate with each other`", so that `non-HTTP` protocol applications can obtain the `user's real IP` instead of the `gateway's IP` in the container.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my friends, I have found a good way to temporarily meet my needs
Manually proxy traffic by directly changing iptables instead of docker gateway.

For example, to forward 25566 traffic to 172.17.0.2:25565, add two new iptable rules:

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 25566 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:25565

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.17.0.2 --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT

The “ppp0” is the network card to monitor the traffic.
In this way, traffic can be manually forwarded into the container without being handed over to the docker gateway for forwarding.